# Rails Polymorphic Associations: getter and setter methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getter-setter, polymorphic-associations

My current project allows `Doctors` to have many `Patients` with which I can do the following:

```
dennis = Patient.create
frank = Doctor.create
dennis.update(doctor: frank)
dennis.doctor #=> frank
frank.patients #=> [dennis, ...]
```

But now I'd like to add a class Hospital, that can also have many patients. I don't want to just add another `has_many` to the `Hostpital` class because `Patient` 'ownership' may change again and eventually my patient model will be littered with foreign key fields, all but one of which will be empty. A polymorphic association appears to be just what I am looking for: a `Patient` can be 'owned' by either a `Doctor` or a `Hospital`:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients, as: :owner
end

class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients, as: :owner
end
```

This allows us to do the following:

```
dennis = Patient.create
frank = Doctor.create
dennis.update(owner: frank)
dennis.owner #=> frank
frank.patients #=> [dennis, ...]
```

We cannot, however, call `dennis.doctor` to return `frank`. I understand that the owner may not always be an instance of the `Doctor` class, but much of my current code uses the `#doctor` and `#doctor=` methods. So I figured I could just define them:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

  def patient=(patient)
    self.owner_id = patient.id
    self.owner_type = "Patient"
  end

  def patient
    return nil unless self.owner
    self.owner.class == Patient ? self.owner : nil
  end

end
```

This seemed to work fine, however this association is still not reflected in my database. I have some custom SQL queries that reference `patients.doctor`. This now throws `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'patients.doctor'` with the polymorphic association.

Is there a better way I could be implementing this? At this point, going back through all of my code and sql queries to change `.doctor` to `.owner` would be prohibitively time consuming.

**TL;DR** Trying to switch from has_many to polymorphic association, but I'd like to keep the convenient getter and setter methods (as well as the associations in my database) provided by the has_many relationship.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For what it is worth, I strongly recommend avoiding polymorphic associations. They are very difficult to enforce in the database (data integrity) because you lose the ability to have foreign key constraints. If you have a foreign key for each possible owner then you can use foreign keys and check constraints. This is done very effectively in my work projects (maybe someday we will make it open-source). We also have getter and setter methods (`owner` and `owner=`) like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I don't highly recommend this, because it's decently hacky and relies on skirting around several Rails behaviors, which is error-prone and never very future-proof. E.g. you will also have to override the `build_doctor`, `create_doctor`, and `create_doctor!` methods if you use them, which I have not done below. I also agree with @doctor_of_ogz in that if you can avoid a polymorphic association, you should. It's not clear to me immediately what the best solution would be, but you might want to more heavily consider multiple foreign key columns as it might be worth the extra nils.

But if you don't want to go that route, what you want should be as follows:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :doctor, ->{joins(:patients).where(patients: {owner_type: "Doctor"})}, foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :hospital, ->{joins(:patients).where(patients: {owner_type: "Hospital"})}, foreign_key: "owner_id"

  def doctor(*args)
    owner_type == "Doctor" ? super : nil
  end

  def doctor=(doctor)
    super
    self.owner = doctor
  end

  def hospital(*args)
    owner_type == "Hospital" ? super : nil
  end

  def hospital=(hospital)
    super
    self.owner = hospital
  end
end
```

Explanation:

The association add a scope on resource_type to allow you to define the association correctly for joins and preloads and the likes. But you need to explicitly add the `joins` to the scope if you intend on using the instance method `patient.doctor` (try it without, you'll see what happens).

I've still use method overrides on the `doctor` and `hospital` instance methods because if you call `patient.hospital`, it will return a `Hospital` it finds one that has a `Patient` and where the `Hospital`'s `id` matches the current `patient`'s `owner_id`, even if `patient.owner_type == "Doctor"`. Rails is generating a query on the `Hospital` model not considering the instance we're calling it from. This is where it begins to feel hacky and not recommended, but the override solves that issue simply by switching on `self.owner_type` as you've already done, but here we can now just use `super`, which gets you Rails' caching behavior and any other frills built into Rails' association getter methods. Similarly, the setter method `doctor=` does not set `owner_type`, so I overrode it again similarly to your existing method, but with `super`. Note that I call super *first* in case a bad argument is supplied (e.g. you pass in a `Hospital` to `doctor=`, which will raise a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`), in which case it won't change `self.owner_type`. Then, rather than simply saying `self.owner_type = "Doctor"`, I opted for `self.owner = doctor`, which *does* set `owner_type`, and also knows to fill the cache of the `:owner` association

I wrote a little more detail about this solution [here](http://www.speaksoftly.io/)